Cannot read multipart/form-data body: unexpected EOF. Using fasthttp POST
type FastHttpRestClient struct {
    client *fasthttp.Client
}

func (c *FastHttpRestClient) PostForm(request Request) ([]byte, error) {
    bodyBuffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
    bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuffer)

    req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
    //Header
    if request.Headers != nil {
        for k, v := range request.Headers {
            req.Header.Set(k, v)
        }
    }

    // Add form data fields
    if request.FormData != nil {
        err := writeFieldsData(bodyWriter, request.FormData)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    if request.FileFields != nil {
        err := writeFilesData(bodyWriter, request.FileFields)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
    req.Header.SetMethod(fasthttp.MethodPost)
    req.SetRequestURI(request.URL)
    req.SetBody(bodyBuffer.Bytes())
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", bodyWriter.FormDataContentType())

    resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)

    err := bodyWriter.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := c.client.Do(req, resp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    body := resp.Body()
    return body, nil
}

func writeFieldsData(bodyWriter *multipart.Writer, fields map[string]string) error {
    for k, v := range fields {
        fieldWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormField(k)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = fieldWriter.Write([]byte(v))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func writeFilesData(bodyWriter *multipart.Writer, fileFields map[string][]*multipart.FileHeader) error {
    for fieldName, fileHeaders := range fileFields {
        for _, fileHeader := range fileHeaders {
            fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile(fieldName, fileHeader.Filename)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            file, err := fileHeader.Open()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

I've developed a function for HTTP service, but unfortunately, it's encountering some issues. My formData containing one File and two data fields. However, upon posting to our API, which supports formData, I'm encountering an unexpected error. Specifically, when I attempted to inspect the response using fmt.Println(string(body)), I received the following error message: "cannot read multipart/form-data body: unexpected EOF". Thank you in advance for your help!

Perhaps the request you're passing into this function is empty?

Not empty, request have values because I hardcoded.
